# File Reader doesn't load

Tags: javascript, filereader

I'm dropping a external file in the browser (chrome), but the `onload` function doesn't fire.

```
drop: function(e) {    
    console.log("drop");
    var file = e.dataTransfer.files
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(file) {
        console.log(file.target.result);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);        
}
```

Comment: If `console.log("drop");` is executed, than I would try to move `reader.onload` before `reader.readAsDataURL`

Comment: sry wrote this wrong at the first time i changed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok i got it i have to write

```
var file = e.dataTransfer.files[0]
```

instead of

```
var file = e.dataTransfer.files
```

This is the kind of typos im living for :)

Comment: happens to the best of us! lol!

Comment: Brian, please don't make fun of 2 year old posts i asked about languages i have no idea about ;-)